# Does Stack Overflow have an Amazon affiliate ID that I can use on my links?

Tags: discussion, advertising

On occasion, I make a book recommendation. It will look something like the following (markup expanded):

```
The following has a detailed treatment on ...

  * [ Windows Internals (6th ed), Part I ] (http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0735648735)
  * [ Windows Internals (6th ed), Part II ] (http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0735665877)
```

Does Stack Overflow have an Amazon affiliate ID? If so, is it possible to insert it into URL so the site makes some money on the link?

Comment: Yes, a Amazon affiliation ID is *already* inserted.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Martin. I'll make sure to test it next time :)

Comment: How altruistic of you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Stack Exchange has a Amazon affiliation account. Amazon links are automatically rewritten (on rendering) to insert that ID. See [Auto-inserting Stack Overflow affiliate into all Amazon book links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links):

> from this point on, all Amazon book links posted on all sites will automatically be rewritten to add our affiliate link